# Drawing diagrams inside a particular commutative diagram

Tags: diagrams, commutative-diagrams, xymatrix

I have difficulty in drawing the following diagram by XY matrix. It would be nice if anyone from this forum can help me out by giving any suggestions.

[image]

Many thanks for considering my request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very long for a comment. I have done a simple general example, with the same tips of `tikz-cd` package using `cmtip` option. If you increase the center symbol `\circlearrowright` (or another similar symbol that you have drawn with your hand), you can add others `\mathlarger` or to use `scalerel` package instead of `relsize`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix{\ar @{} [dr] |{{\mathlarger\circlearrowright}}
{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\
\downarrow\\
k\{e_{1}\}
\end{pmatrix} }\ar[d] \ar[r] & {\begin{pmatrix} k\{e'\} \\
\downarrow \scriptstyle j\\
k\{e\}
\end{pmatrix} } \ar[d] \\
{\begin{pmatrix} k\{e''\} \\
\downarrow \scriptstyle i\\
k\{e\}
\end{pmatrix}} \ar[r] & {\begin{pmatrix} k\{e',e''\} \\
\downarrow \scriptstyle (j,i)\\
k\{e\}
\end{pmatrix}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer (+1), however I can't figured out, what is the purpose of the circular arrow in the middle of the diagram. OP should reconsider what it means and consequently if directions of arrows between nodes are correct:-)

Comment: @Zarko But it not true :-) ahahah ahaha. I think the user wants someone to do the drawing :-) I don't know what he wants. You are very kind. My sincerest regards.